# Detach XCode's Navigator into its own window?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

Right now, my average xcode window is just an editor window with the navigator on the left.

Is there any way I can detach the navigator into a separate window?

I've tried:

1. Making a new complete window, and hiding the editor. This doesn't work, when I try to drag the navigator to cover the entire window, it won't go all the way. It's strange that this works to create a debugger-only window, and not a navigator-only window.
2. Making a behavior in the preferences, to show the navigator and hide the editor. When I run this behavior, it shows the navigator and hides the editor, but puts the debugger in its place. When I add "hide the debugger" to the behavior, I get the same result: navigator plus debugger.

Eternal gratitude to whoever can end my suffering!

(xcode 4.6, mac 10.8)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this. The Xcode application's UI was not written to be able to do what you're asking for.

Comment: That's a shame... it seems like such a simple use case. Is it wrong to want to do this? Is there some sort of xcode-zen that I'm not attuned to?

Comment: Xcode's UI was changed to a single window UI as of version 4.